# Compiler chooses invalid template specialization and fails

Tags: c++, templates

The code below is a snippet from a code base I am working on. Ideally the library user could partially specify the `Fixed` type assuming that they want to use the same backing integer and precision throughout their code (`FixedBase` values are only comparable if they have the same backing `value_t`).

Surprisingly, this doesn't compile. The instantiation in `main` chooses the first template and then fails because `11` isn't a type... despite there being a valid specialization.

```
#include <cstdint>

/******** Library code *********/

template<typename value_t, std::size_t MAX_PREC>
class FixedBase {};

template<typename value_t, std::size_t MAX_PREC, int L, int R>
class Fixed : public FixedBase<value_t, MAX_PREC> {};

/********* User code **********/

// User specialization
template<int L, int R>
class Fixed<int64_t, 64, L, R> {};


int main(void) {

    Fixed<11, -3> a;

    return 0;
}
```

The main question is, why is it choosing the first specialization and failing, rather than pick the valid second specialization? How do I get the compiler to pick the right one?

A secondary question is, is there a better way to partially specify template parameters? I'm thinking there might some special `using` syntax I'm not familiar with, and haven't found while Googling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood how specialization works, specialization doesn't change the template parameter list.

In this case, you can use alias:

```
template<int L, int R>
using my_type = Fixed<int64_t, 64, L, R>;

int main(void) {

    my_type<11, -3> a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the using syntax I was looking for. Could you elaborate what you mean by "specialization doesn't change the template parameter list".

Answer (score 3):

When you add a partial specialization like

```
template<int L, int R>
class Fixed<int64_t, 64, L, R> {};
```

You haven't made a template for `Fixed` that just lets you specify `L` and `R` like you do in `Fixed<11, -3> a;`.  What you have done is tell the compiler that if it sees a

```
Fixed<int64_t, 64, some_int, some_other_int>
```

then it should use the specialization since they first two parameters match.

Long story short: You always have to specify all the primary template members.